# Getting object ID inside form.py

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to check if my instance.id is not equal object.id in form.py so I can edit the post whenever all conditions are met.
form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.owner = kwargs.pop('owner')
        super(TopicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].empty_label = 'أختر الدولة'
        self.fields['city'].empty_label = 'أختر المدينة'
        self.fields['neighborhood'].empty_label = 'أختر الحي'
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = 'أختر القسم'
        self.fields['sub_category'].empty_label = 'أختر الفئة'
        self.fields['sub_sub_category'].empty_label = 'أختر النوع'

    class Meta:
        model   = Topic
        fields  = ['topic', 'category', 'sub_category', 'sub_sub_category', 'country', 'city',
                   'neighborhood', 'price', 'insurance', 'description', ]

        error_messages = {
            'topic': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
                        },
            'category': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'sub_category': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'sub_sub_category': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'country': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'city': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'neighborhood': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'price': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة",
                'number': "الرجاء ادخال رقم صحيح"
            },
            'insurance': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            },
            'description': {
                'required': "الخانة هذي مطلوبة"
            }
                            }

        widgets  = {
                    'topic': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'required': True,
                                    'placeholder': 'الرجاء إدخال عنوان'
                    }),
                               
                    'country': forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'required': True,
                                    'empty_label': 'أختر الدولة'
                    }),
                    'city': forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'required': True,
                                    'placeholder': 'أختر المدينة'
                    }),
                    'neighborhood': forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'required': True,
                                    'placeholder': 'أختر الحي'
                    }),

                    'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                        'required': True,
                        # 'placeholder': 'السعر',

                    }),

                    'insurance': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                        'required': True,
                        # 'placeholder': 'التأمين',

                    }),


                    'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                        'required': True,
                        'placeholder': 'الرجاء إدخال الوصف هنا...'
                    }),


        }

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(TopicForm, self).clean()
        id=cleaned_data.get('id') 
        category = cleaned_data.get('category')
        sub_category = cleaned_data.get('sub_category')
        sub_sub_category = cleaned_data.get('sub_sub_category')
        country = cleaned_data.get('country')
        city = cleaned_data.get('city')
        neighborhood = cleaned_data.get('neighborhood')
        for instance in Topic.objects.all():
            if instance.id != id:
                if instance.owner == self.owner:
                    if instance.category == category:
                        if instance.sub_category == sub_category:
                            if instance.sub_sub_category == sub_sub_category:
                                if instance.country == country:
                                    if instance.city == city:
                                        if instance.neighborhood == neighborhood:
                                            raise forms.ValidationError('قوانين الموقع تمنع تكرار المنشورات')
```

I know this code is not valid

```
id=cleaned_data.get('id')
if instance.id != id:
```

how to rephrase it to make it valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to exclude the post and the problem solved

```
for instance in Topic.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk):
```